# Shadow parent function/method in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the follow code:

```js
export class Foo extends Function {
    bar() {}
}

export class Foo2 extends Foo {
    bar(a) {}
}
```

This throws the error `Property 'bar' in type 'Foo2' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Foo'. Type '(a: any) => any' is not assignable to type '() => any'.`.

Is there any way to tell typescript to *allow* me to have a child class shadow it's parent's method? I understand typescript wants polymorphism to work - if I call `new Foo2.bar()`, it needs to have something to run. I just want it to run `Foo.bar` in this case, or require me to cast to Foo first, or something.

Here's my use-case. I'm trying to create some `.d.ts` files for plain javascript classes. They aren't built using ES classes, but just with plain functions like so:

```js
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {}
Foo.prototype.baz = function() {}

function Foo2() {}
Foo2.prototype = new Foo();
Foo2.prototype.bar = function(a) {}
```

In plain javascript, this is just fine. An instance of `Foo2` will have a method for `baz`, inherited from `Foo`, and a method for `bar` taking 1 argument, which replaces it's parent's. This is allowed in other languages like C# as well with shadowing. But I don't know how to represent this behavior in Typescript. The only workaround I can think of is just to not use inheritance, and manually redeclare all inherited methods that aren't overwritten, but of course this would be a real pain to maintain so I'd love it if there was a workaround.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

One idea is to use the [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in the base class so descendent classes can override it with any number of arguments. This way the type of each function parameter is not erased.

```js
declare class Foo extends Function {
  bar(...args: any[]): void;
}

declare class Foo2 extends Foo {
  bar(a: string): void
}
```

### Solution 2

The equivalent from JavaScript to Typescript would be the following. Just use `Function` as the base type to assign every type of function. The drawback is that the function's parameter type is erased.

```js
export class Foo extends Function {
  bar: Function = () => {}
}

export class Foo2 extends Foo {
  bar = (a: string) => {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I see how this works, but there are two issues for my use-case. First, this is for a `.d.ts` file, so I can't actually declare method bodies or use assignment in an "ambient context". I could solve that by just saying `bar: Function;` (with no params) for all functions, but that leads to problem 2: This would erase the names and types of all arguments. Is there any way to make this work in a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: I've added another solution to the answer. Please check out `Solution 1`.

Comment: Thanks @lepsh. Solution 1 is a smart idea. It may help in some cases, but I'm not sure it will work in all cases, since I have chains of inheritance (e.g. `Foo3 extends Foo2`), and the child class' arguments are not necessarily a superset of their parent's. Let me know if you have other ideas - otherwise I'll take this one as far as I can go.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to tell typescript to allow me to have a child class shadow it's parent's method? I understand typescript wants polymorphism to work - if I call new Foo2.bar(), it needs to have something to run. I just want it to run Foo.bar in this case, or require me to cast to Foo first, or something.

No, it's not really possible. Other languages like Java and C# will automatically call the right overloaded method based on the signature, but that's not how things work in Javascript and therefore Typescript.

It is actually possible to provide multiple signatures for a function. The below example uses the first 2 definitions to determine the overloads, but then the third one is the real implementation:

```js
export class Foo {
    bar(a: number): number;
    bar(a: string): string;
    bar(a: number|number): string|number {

    }
}
```

But with these overloads you are required to figure how the function was called and narrow the type.

If you extend in Typescript, the subclass must be compatible with the parent class. The easiest way to do this in your case seems to be like this:

```js
export class Foo2 extends Foo {
    bar(a?: number) {
      if (a===undefined) return super.bar();
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I'm actually not talking about method overloading, but just shadowing. I know in JS you can't have an object with multiple methods having the same name. For this reason, I believe Typescript requires overloaded methods to have the same number of arguments, so that doesn't address my use-case.

Comment: @thomas88wp the general behavior of what you're describing with javascript is that method of the subclass just gets undefined, so just make it optional and you should be good?